# selenium wont work with Firefox or Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am trying to learn python web scraping, but I cannot get selenium to work with either browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

This is all the code I have and I get this for a error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\codingpractice\python\python challenge.com.py", line 2, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 135, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x00A11350>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del__
    self.stop()
  File "C:\Users\tjhall\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
    if self.process is None:
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

I have tried everything I can find on the internet from adding the path to the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox("C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe")
```

to adding it the the PATH in my environment variables. I can't seem to figure this out...

Comment: Looks like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For both Firefox and Chrome you now need to download [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) / [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).These drivers are necessary to communicate between your installed browser and selenium. So you need:

- Install selenium for python (`pip install selenium`)
- Download [drivers](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) for the browser you want to use (chromedriver, geckodriver, operadriver etc)
- Install the browser you want to use on your system (probably already have this)

Now you can add the geckodriver to your path as metioned in this [anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40208762/1768843). Or you can set it up directly in your code like this:

Chome:
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver.exe')`

Firefox:
`driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='/opt/geckoDriver/geckodriver.exe')`

Comment: I was able to get it working with your information. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried lots of different ways to install selenium and still keep getting an error: FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py in start(self)
     75                                             stderr=self.log_file,
---> 76                                             stdin=PIPE)
     77         except TypeError:

Answer (score 0):

According to the line in your message

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

you do not have geckodriver.exe. You need to download it from [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver), put exe in the directory where Python script is located and try code below:

Please try this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

gecko = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'geckodriver'))
binary = FirefoxBinary(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,executable_path=gecko+'.exe')
browser.get('http:///www.google.com')
browser.close()
```